# Flatpak fails to generate .flatpakref

Tags: python, linux, xml, packaging, flatpak

I am trying to package my flatpak package into a .flatpakref for uploading into flathub.
Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component type="desktop-application">
    <id>com.sebicodes.Prt</id>
    <metadata_license>GNU General Public License v3.0</metadata_license>
    <name>Please Run That</name>
    <summary>A python socket app for letting a friend execute a command on your system without opening ports or using an ssh server</summary>


</component>
```

And here's the flatpak error:

```
Actualizando rama de «appstream»
F: Couldn't load commit <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component type="desktop-application">
    <id>com.sebicodes.Prt</id>
    <metadata_license>GNU General Public License v3.0</metadata_license>
    <description>
   <p>A python script that uses sockets for letting you execute code in a socket server (that runs this app) for executing commands in another computer without creating an ssh server.</p>
    </description>
    <name>Please Run That</name>
    <summary>A python socket app for letting a friend execute a command on your system without opening ports or using an ssh server</summary>


</component> (ref app/org.sebicodes.Prt/x86_64/com.sebicodes.Prt.appdata.xml)
**
flatpak:ERROR:../flatpak/common/flatpak-utils.c:5679:_flatpak_repo_generate_appstream: assertion failed: (commit_v != NULL)
Bail out! flatpak:ERROR:../flatpak/common/flatpak-utils.c:5679:_flatpak_repo_generate_appstream: assertion failed: (commit_v != NULL)
Abortado (`core' generado)
```

What should I try?

XML validators and appstream tells it's great also, asking ChatGPT didn't solve the issue.